# Incrementing filename using a counter if file exists - New file not detected as existing

Tags: swift, macos

I need to save files to a directory,if the file exists I need to rename the file.So I'm using while loop for the same.The strange thing is , the while loop understands that there exists a  file in the first execution and increments the counter and assign the variable, but when the newly generated file name exists it seems not to detect that

```
            let mappedFilename=inputfile.lastPathComponent
            var outputfile=outdir+"/"+mappedFilename
            var filenamecounter=1
            while(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputfile))
            {
                var test=URL(fileURLWithPath: outputfile).deletingPathExtension().absoluteString + "_" +
                filenamecounter.description+".pdf";
                  //doing this because, if directly assigning to output file,the assignment seems not to work 
                outputfile=test
                filenamecounter=filenamecounter+1                
            }
```

Example

[image]

You can see the return value of the loop here

[image]

Comment: See the documentation of `fileExists(atPath:)`. "Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the file system or a particular file on the file system is not recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions."

Comment: @Willeke I managed to fix the issue by creating a URL from the string and using its `path` property.